# Vue - In a reusuable component running a method only for the respective component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have some reusuable components and whenever I add one, it gets pushed in an array etc. The question is: How do I make sure the methods in those reusuable components only run for the respective component and not for all of them.

Example: Using an @click event to open a modal, the modal shows up the exact number of times I added the component (expected, but I want to change this so it only shows up once and only for the respective component).

Adding components:

```
<template v-for="(comp, index) in comps">
  <component
       :is="comp"
       :key="index"
       :currentIndex="currentIndex"
       v-on:delete="deleteComp($event)"
   ></component>
</template>
```

Same method inside some components:

```
methods: {
  showModal() {
   this.$bvModal.show('modalSmall');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to pass an id as props for the different components.

```html
<template v-for="(comp, index) in comps">
  <component
       ....
       :id="comps.id" // you could create a computed property to generate an id based on a number or some other unique identifier
       ....
   ></component>
</template>
```

Then in your component,

#### Component.vue

```js
props: {
  id: {
    type: string,
    required: true
  }
}

methods: {
  showModal() {
   this.$bvModal.show(id);
  }
}
```

Remember to change your id for each modal, in the template, from `modalSmall` to `id` (the id prop).